# Convert html table into xml using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I got stuck with making the two options in converting html table into 2 types of xml.
I needed to make a xslt to convert Html table like this

```
<categories>1 row</categories>
<dataset>1 column</dataset>
<table caption="City statistics">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="1">Name</th> <th id="2">Population</th> <th id="3">Area</th><th id="4">Elevation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="1">Moscow</td> <td id="2">4.7</td> <td id="3">11.54</td> <td id="4">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="1">London</td> <td id="2">6</td> <td id="3">15.54</td> <td id="4">15</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Into xml file like this if the  had 1 row as a value(means taking categories out of header where id > 1).

```
 <chart caption='City statistics' xAxisName='City name' yAxisName='Values'>

       <categories>
          <category label='Population' />
          <category label='Area' />
          <category label='Elevation' />
       </categories>

       <dataset seriesName='Moscow'>
          <set value='4.7' />
          <set value='11.54'/>
          <set value='13' />
       </dataset>

       <dataset seriesName='London'>
          <set value='6'/>
          <set value='15.54'/>
          <set value='15'/>
       </dataset>
    </chart>
```

And I got this xsl from Miam84 as a help here. And this is a solution for the first condition

And I needed to make a one xsl for two conditions.
The otherwise condition is the xml where the   had 1 column as a value( need to take categories from  where id=1).

```
<chart caption='City statistics' xAxisName='Сharacteristics' yAxisName='Values'>

           <categories>
              <category label='Moscow' />
              <category label='London' />
           </categories>

           <dataset seriesName='Population'>
              <set value='4.7' />
              <set value='6'/>

           </dataset>

           <dataset seriesName='Area'>
              <set value='11.54'/>
              <set value='15.54'/>

           </dataset>

           <dataset seriesName='Elevation'>
              <set value='13' />
              <set value='15'/>

           </dataset>
        </chart>
```

What I tried to do is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <!-- Default template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//categories[@place='head']" >
        <chart caption="" xAxisName="" yAxisName="Values">
            <xsl:attribute name="xAxisName">
                <xsl:value-of select="html/categories"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="caption">
                <xsl:value-of select="html/table/@caption"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="html/table/thead"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="html/table/tbody/tr"/>
        </chart>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <chart caption="" xAxisName="" yAxisName="Values">
            <xsl:attribute name="xAxisName">
                <xsl:value-of select="html/dataset"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="caption">
                <xsl:value-of select="html/table/@caption"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="html/table/thead"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="html/table/tbody/tr"/>
            </chart>
            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template for the thead = categories container -->
    <xsl:template match="tbody">

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//categories[@place='head']" >


            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <categories>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tr/td[@id=1]"/>
                </categories>
            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="thead">

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//categories[@place='head']" >
                <categories>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tr/th[@id &gt; 1]"/>
                </categories>

            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template for the th = each category -->
    <xsl:template match="th">
    <xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:when test="//categories[@place='head']" >
                <category>
                <xsl:attribute name="label">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                </category>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <dataset seriesName="">
            <xsl:attribute name="seriesName">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            </dataset>
            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>   

    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template for the tr = the dataset -->

    <xsl:template match="tr">
    <xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:when test="//categories[@place='head']" >
                <dataset seriesName="">
            <xsl:attribute name="seriesName">
                <xsl:value-of select="td[@id=1]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="td[@id &gt; 1]"/>
        </dataset>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
            <dataset seriesName="">
            <xsl:attribute name="seriesName">
                <xsl:value-of select="th[@id &gt; 1]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            </dataset>


            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>   


    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template for the td = the set tag -->
    <xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//categories[@place='head']" >
                <set value="">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </set>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <category>
                <xsl:attribute name="label">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                </category>



            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>   



    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="html">

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have an html source but it's not really a HTML file because you have non-html tags in it (category, dataset)... So something is wrong in your question

Assuming you have an xml source file that you called html in your question, this xsl should do the trick :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <!-- Default template -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <chart caption="" xAxisName="City name" yAxisName="Values">
      <xsl:attribute name="caption">
        <xsl:value-of select="root/table/@caption" />
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/table/thead"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/table/tbody/tr"/>   
    </chart>  
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- template for the thead = categories container -->
  <xsl:template match="thead">
    <categories>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tr/th[@id &gt; 1]" />        
    </categories>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- template for the th = each category -->
  <xsl:template match="th">
    <category>
      <xsl:attribute name="label">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </category>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for the tr = the dataset -->
  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <dataset seriesName="">
      <xsl:attribute name="seriesName">
        <xsl:value-of select="td[@id=1]" />
      </xsl:attribute>  
      <xsl:apply-templates select="td[@id &gt; 1]" />       
    </dataset>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- template for the td = the set tag -->
  <xsl:template match="td">
    <set value="">
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </set>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But you have to know that a well formed xml has a root element, so I took your xml source surrounded by a `root` element :

```
<root>   
  <categories>1 row</categories>
  <dataset>1 column</dataset>
  <table caption="City statistics">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="1">Name</th> 
        <th id="2">Population</th> 
        <th id="3">Area</th>
        <th id="4">Elevation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="1">Moscow</td> 
        <td id="2">4.7</td> 
        <td id="3">11.54</td> 
        <td id="4">13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="1">London</td> 
        <td id="2">6</td> 
        <td id="3">15.54</td> 
        <td id="4">15</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</root>
```